# Build with declarative pipeline does not work Jenkins, but works with Scripted pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am getting sources from `git`, next my step is replace of needed variables in these sources, next step build these sources in the docker container. How it works with scripted pipeline.

```
node('jenkinsslave') {
  stage('Remove old sources'){
     sh 'rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/*'
  }
  stage('Get sources'){
     checkout scm
  }
  stage('Replace variables'){
      sh """
      /scripts/replace_variables.sh "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME"
      """
  }
  stage('Run in container')
  docker.image('maven').inside('-u root:root') {
      sh "mvn clean install"
  }
  stage('Chown to user Jenkins'){
      sh "sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/"
  }
}
```

It works, without any probles. So, i tried to rewrite this to declarative pipeline. Look please.

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'jenkinsslave'}

    stages {
        stage('Remove old sources'){
            steps {
                echo 'remove old resources'
                sh 'rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/*'
                }
        }
        stage('Checkout SCM') {
            steps {
                echo '> Checking out the source control ...'
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Replace variables') {
            steps {
                echo '> Replace needed variables ...'
                sh """
                /scripts/replace_variables.sh "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME"
                """
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                   image 'maven:latest'
                   args '-u root:root'
                   }
            }
            steps {
                sh "mvn clean install"
            }
        }
        stage('Chown to user Jenkins'){
            steps {
            echo 'Chown to user Jenkins'
            sh "sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the second variant, yes, it builds sources, but in the second workspace. And of course, my step with replace of needed variables does not work.
For example, i have workspace, `my_job`. But it creates, `my_job@2`. Also, i tried to add

```
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }
```

Result was the same. How i can fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

First you can use this to clean your WS after every build, this will clean the workspace up nicely:

```
     post { 
      always { 
          cleanWs()
      }
  }
```

Regarding the my_job@2. Are you running concurrent builds? If  not then i would log in to the jenkins machine and delete the workspaces related to this job and have the post block referred to earlier in your declarative pipeline.